# Loading notifier

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

First of all, the app look really great, simple and efficient design. Good job guys !!

For few actions in the app, like searching, filtering, etc .. there is nothing to tell the user that something is loading. Even the native "loading" in the status bar doesn't exists.

I really love to see what's going on when I use an app, like the main things: a loading for any action.

Please, allow a loading icon somewhere everytime an action need to use the network.

Comment: Hi j0k, thank you for the valuable feedback. Do you think you could file these as three separate questions on meta? It would make it easier for the right person to handle it.

Comment: No problem, I'll do it :)

Answer (score 2):

I have **added loading indicators** for question listings and when filtering. We will try to add more of these where needed, so if you spot any other usecases, feel free to add them to this question. This will be available in 0.1.17

[image: Loading indicators]

Comment: But why don't you use the default one from the status bar instead?

Comment: Because I think this is approach much more visible, and doesn't leave us with a totally blank screen. Also some people don't notice the status bar as much, although it's useful in more cluttered situations.

Comment: Well, that's your point of view. I agree that a blank screen isn't the best experience. But why don't you use both? I'm almost sure people are aware of the status bar loader **because** this is the default behavior on iOS. I really don't like app that doesn't notify me when they are accessing the network. They let you in an *unknown* state, waiting for something to happen but without being sure that something will happen ...

Comment: Sure, it's probably something we can add at some point.